# How do I display the Designation role corresponding to the member

Tags: sql, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to display the Designation role corresponing to the member,

What I am trying to achieve,

```
Chairman |
         |
         President - Heading
          - member name
         Vice President - Heading
          - member name
```

I have a chairman with subordinates who are divided based on designation ID,

To achieve this, I have created 3 table,

**statechairmen**

```
id | first_name | from | to  

1 | Chairman | 2019 | 2020
```

**statemembers**

```
id | first_name | chairman_id | designation_id 

  1 | Member 1 | 1 | P (inherted from designation_code of statedesignation)

  1 | Member 2 | 1 | VP (inherted from designation_code of statedesignation)
```

**statedesignation**

```
id | designation_code | designation_name | designation_desc

  1 | P | President | President Description. 
  1 | VP | Vice President | President Description.
```

***Can the database design be better ?? . Any other suggestions***

I would like to display the list of members followed by their designation:

I tried ordering the table but, I am not able to bring in the designation for the corresponding members,

My controller to bring in the Statemembers under the chairman

```
$statemembers = StateChairman::find($id)->statemembers()->orderBy('designation_id')->get();
dd($statemembers);
```

**I am getting result- List of all state members -**

```
But when I try this 
$statedesignation = Statemembers::find($id)->statedesignations()->get();
dd($statedesignation);
```

**For this one I am only getting result with Id 1 in the Statedesignation, 
that is President, The Vice President is ignored,**

I am only getting Designation **President** since find($id) brings up only 1 or corresponding id

Model:

**State Chairman:**

```
    class Statechairman extends Model
{
    public function statemembers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Statemembers','chairman_id','id');
    }
}
```

**StateMembers:**

```
class Statemembers extends Model
{
    public function statechairman(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Statechairman','chairman_id','id');
    }
```

**State Designations:**

```
 public function statemembers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Statemembers');
```

I am clueless on how to achieve the above requirement,

I also though of removing the designation_id from the statemembers table and add designation_name and display it directly on the page.
Updating the table some thing like this,

```
id | first_name | chairman_id | designation_id 

  1 | Member 1 | 1 | President
  2 | Member 2 | 1 | Vice President
```

But thats not a good practice.

Please provide me some insights for the above question.

Comment: statechairmen hasMany statemembers and
statemembers belongsTo statedesignation

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you should use polymorphic relationships or `has-many-through` relationships

[Laravel Polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Hope it helps :)